# How to Finding Array Differences using postgres SQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in Postgres DB as below:

| SOURCE | Entity | DiFF |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PRD | E1,E2,E3,E4,E5 |  |
| MC | E1,E2 |  |
| GT1 | E1,E2,E3 |  |

I Need to insert the differences Between PRD and  MC,GT1 into the DIFF column using postgres SQL

Expected result

| SOURCE | Entity | DiFF |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PRD | E1,E2,E3,E4,E5 |  |
| MC | E1,E2 | E3,E4,E5 |
| GT1 | E1,E2,E3 | E4,E5 |

Answer (score 1):

This is a terrible data model, but anyways:

The following query will get the "difference" between the column separated lists (not arrays) for `MC` and `GT1`:

```
select source,
       (select string_agg(xp.item, ',')
        from data p
          cross join unnest(string_to_array(p.entity, ',')) as xp(item) 
        where p.source = 'PRD'
          and not exists (select *
                          from unnest(string_to_array(d.entity, ',')) as x(item)
                          where xp.item = x.item)) as diff
from data d
where source in ('MC', 'GT1')
```

Given your sample data this returns:

```
source | diff    
-------+---------
MC     | E3,E4,E5
GT1    | E4,E5
```

This can be used to UPDATE the table (not "insert"!)

```
update data
  set diff = t.diff
from (
  select source,
         (select string_agg(xp.item, ',')
          from data p
            cross join unnest(string_to_array(p.entity, ',')) as xp(item) 
          where p.source = 'PRD'
            and not exists (select *
                            from unnest(string_to_array(d.entity, ',')) as x(item)
                            where xp.item = x.item)) as diff
  from data d
  where source in ('MC', 'GT1')
) t
where data.source = t.source;
```

Comment: HI  https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name